# Where did the vial of ooze come from?

Tags: tmnt-secret-of-the-ooze

In *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II: Secret of the Ooze*, Professor Perry is about to dispose of the last vial of ooze when The Foot attacks and takes it, kidnapping him as well.

He is then forced, by Shredder, to use the final vial to create Tokka and Rahzar.

Yet, at the end of the film Shredder has another vial of ooze. Where did this vial of ooze come from?

Comment: Also in the movie Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles : Out of the shadows, Ralph destroys all the ooze, I'm assuming that it might be completely destroyed. But I don't think so!!!